# find id of currently selected view in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, view, swt, rcp

I have many views opened while My Eclipse RCP application is running.Could anyone show me the way how can i get view id(not secondary view id) of currently selected view in my workbench ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I got a way to get view ID of currently selected(opened) view in my application's workbench as following lines of code :

```
IWorkbenchPage wbp = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
String id = wbp.getActivePartReference().getId();
```

And it was what I was seeking for.